# Can the ip of a SMB file share be traced back to me?

Tags: anonymity, ip, file-upload, user-tracking, tracking

The question is pretty much self explanitory

Comment: Can you please describe your question further?

Comment: Response to question body: No, it's not.

Answer (score 4):

The SMB protocol (also CIFS) is meant to share files over the local networks. Since the file is hosted on your computer, there has to be a way to get your address for the client to retrieve it.

Therefore, for the service to work, the file has to be able to be traced to your computer.